# Permuting and combining the values based on the key

Tags: c#, algorithms, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate a table which would show all possible combinations based on the key. To make it more clear lets say I have a kind of Key, Value pair set(Its mentioned kind of because there are unique keys and different values).  I need to fill the table with all possible combinations of the values with different keys.

[image: Sample input and output]

Now i need to make the key as the heading of the table and add the values accordingly so that there are no duplicate rows and all combinations are present. I am doing it in C#. I could only retrieve these key value pairs from my database based on conditions, but I have no idea how the table can be built.

Are there any examples someone could provide? Or a basic approach I should follow to achieve it?

So far my ideas:

To create an array with size equals number of distinct parameters of key. Add values to the array and then pass a list of the Array to the View.

P.S : My data model is complex. Reference to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298138/designing-my-classes-with-relationships) question would give an idea of a part of my Data model. The value I am talking about comes from the *SetValue* described in the model and the key from another class which is not described (I feel this information is irrelevant as I have already the list of my Key value pairs). I think I have posted the question in the right forum, as I am not asking for any code. If not please let me know the right forum where this question will belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of types like you do in this case (color, fruit, vegetable), then you can do it easily with nested loops. For example:

```
foreach (var color in colors)
{
    foreach (var fruit in fruits)
    {
        foreach (var veg in vegetables)
        {
            rows.Add(new Row(color, fruit, vegetable));
        }
    }
}
```

That gets unwieldy if your number of different things grows, though.

You can, however, generalize that to a class that will generate permutations for any number of different things.

Comment: I am not having fixed number of types. But I could figure out a way to do it. By recursively calculating the Cartesian Product. [here][http://stackoverflow.com/a/33756164/5243291] you can find the link to the answer i did to solve the task.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do a more versatile version, that allows multiple properties with list of values to be permuted. It is rather silly (does not use LINQ, as input data is a OrderedDictionary) and can be improved if input data is in a more friendly format.

```
// hold index data for permutations
class IndexData
{
    public int PropIndex { get; set; }
    public int MaxCount { get; set; }
}

// input data - OrderedDictionary helps with the key order, but has serious non-typed drawbacks
var propsValues = new OrderedDictionary()
{
    { "colour", new List<String>() { "red", "blue", "violet", "black", "yellow"}},
    { "fruit", new List<String>() { "apple", "mango", "banana", "banana"}},
    { "vegetable", new List<String>() { "onion", "potato", "tomato"}},
    { "shape", new List<String>() { "round", "oval" }}
};

// compute index containers to help with permutations
var propsIndexes = new Dictionary<String, IndexData>();
var propsKeys = new List<String>();
foreach (var key in propsValues.Keys)
{
    propsKeys.Add((String) key);
    propsIndexes.Add((String) key, new IndexData() { PropIndex = 0, MaxCount = (propsValues[key] as List<String>).Count});
}

int propCount = propsValues.Count;
String lastKey = propsKeys[propCount - 1];

// count the permutations until the "most significant" property (the one changing least often) has reached its count
for (int combinationIndex = 0; ; combinationIndex ++ )
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}: ", combinationIndex + 1);
    foreach (var key in propsValues.Keys)
    {
        int propIndex = propsIndexes[(String)key].PropIndex;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", ((propsValues[(String)key] as List<String>)[propIndex]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    // incrementing indexes
    bool exit = false;
    propsIndexes[lastKey].PropIndex++;

    for (int i = propCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        String propKey = (String)propsKeys[i];

        // current index has reached its count - incrementing previous one and resetting current one
        if (propsIndexes[propKey].PropIndex >= propsIndexes[propKey].MaxCount)
        {
            propsIndexes[propKey].PropIndex = 0;

            // "most significant" property has reached its count
            if (i == 0)
            {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }

            String prevPropKey = (String)propsKeys[i - 1];
            propsIndexes[prevPropKey].PropIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (exit)
        break;
}
```

Comment: I will check if the solution works for me ASAP.  Thanks for your answer.